# Why does Javers store the ID of my audited entities wrapped in quotes?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, javers

I audit changes to a `com.example.TaskSupplier` entity with Javers by annotating the corresponding Spring Data repository

```
@JaversSpringDataAuditable
public interface TaskSupplierRepository extends CrudRepository<TaskSupplier, String> {
}
```

The primary key of this entity is a UUID, so I can retrieve an instance with

```
select * from task_supplier where id = 'f463d538-ceb0-498b-a20b-2bb65286d200';
```

However, the entry in Javers' `jv_global_id` table for this instance wraps the ID in quotes, so in order to retrieve the corresponding row from this table, I have to execute

```
select * from jv_global_id
where type_name = 'com.sourcespace.bidsengine.model.TaskSupplier'
and local_id = '"f463d538-ceb0-498b-a20b-2bb65286d200"';
```

Is this intentional or a bug? I was confused when the query above without the quotes was failing to retrieve anything. I'm using Postgres, Javers 5.14.0, and Spring Boot 2.4.2

Comment: I think this is intentional. `local_id` must be able to store composite keys and therefore a key to be stored is converted into JSON. And that means that a `String` key is stored with quotes. But anyway: all of this is an implementation detail anyway and you should be accessing the tables through the official API only.

Comment: @ThomasKläger in my case I want to use the audit data to explore production issues, rather than using the audit data as part of the application itself. I currently do this using a read-only SQL connection to the database, but maybe there's a better way?

Comment: I don't know enough about javers and your use case, so it is hard to say whether there is a better way. IMHO there is nothing fundamentaly wrong if you access the audit data directly. You loose the higher level support that the javers API supports and you have to explore how javers stores its data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is intentional, it's a JSON type and not a String type. Local Id can be any type in Java, also a Value Object, so it's serialized to JSON.

Comment: I was surprised to see that the `jv_snapshot.state` column is defined as a `text` type, rather than a JSON type. Maybe this is because not all databases support a JSON type?

Comment: yes, it's easier to treat is as text in DB and parse to JSON in Java , since JSON types are dialect-specific